# Can I use Docker Compose with images that use the builder-pattern?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm aware of the new [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/) feature, which works nicely with Docker Compose. However, let's say I'm stuck with the builder-pattern (don't ask)... is there any way to have `docker-compose up` use the build script required by the builder pattern?

Consider the same builder-pattern files from the linked article:

Dockerfile.build

```
FROM golang:1.7.3
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html  
COPY app.go .
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html \
  && CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest  
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY app .
CMD ["./app"]
```

build.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
docker build -t alexellis2/href-counter:build . -f Dockerfile.build

docker create --name extract alexellis2/href-counter:build  
docker cp extract:/go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app ./app  
docker rm -f extract

docker build --no-cache -t alexellis2/href-counter:latest .
rm ./app
```

I could construct a Docker Compose file kinda like this one, but I have no idea how to `cp` the files from the temporary Docker container.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app: 
    build: .
    depends_on:
     - app-build
  app-build:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.build
```

I could build the temporary Docker image/container and run the `cp` by using the first part of the `build.sh` script from above and then using a stripped down compose file, but, then, I might as well just stick with the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach can be using 2 docker-compose calls, combined with a directory mapping:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app: 
    build: .

  app-build:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.build
    volumes:
       - ./build/:/go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/
```

Then:

```
#This will produce local ./build/app artifact
docker-compose build app-build

#Having the previous artifact, will use it:
docker-compose build app
```

Just change this into Dockerfile:

```
COPY build/app .
```

However, I recommend you the Multi Stage Build approach. Hugely simpler than this.

Comment: I agree and will be trying, but we also desperately need Compose to simplify our lives and have a ton of builder-patterned images :(

Answer (score 2):

As I understood, you are asking if it is possible to use something like `docker cp` within the compose file to extract an artifact from the temporary container.

Well, using a shared `volume` is an option for that.

```
version: '3'
    services:
      app: 
        build: .
        depends_on:
         - app-build
        volumes:
        - shared:/source        
      app-build:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile.build
        volumes:
        - shared:/output
    volumes:
      - shared:
```

But you have to add a script in `app` service which will check if `app-build` has finished its work and the artifact is ready.

Using shared volumes is a bit risky. You must know what you are doing.

> Multiple containers can also share one or more data volumes. However, multiple containers writing to a single shared volume can cause data corruption.
>   https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#important-tips-on-using-shared-volumes

There is an issue titled "Add `copy` to the yaml configuration" on github: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1664

I would like to have an option like that in compose file. You can check others' opinions about this on the link above. That issue is closed now but might be opened again.

Answer (score 0):

Docker compose doesn't have build dependencies, those are for determining the startup order of the containers post-build. And it doesn't let you create a container and copy a file out to use in another build. So you're left with the above build script or using the new multi-stage builds if your environment is running at least 17.05.